# Get an Id from EF query then use that to remove records

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, entity-framework

Using EF I would like to remove a user from the Dot database...this all works fine with code like

```
DbContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM activeforums_Attachments where UserId = " + userId);
DbContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM activeforums_Forums_Tracking where UserId = " + userId);
DbContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM activeforums_Poll where UserId = " + userId);
DbContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM activeforums_Poll_Results where UserId = " + userId);
```

I can remove manually using the aspNetUserId with:

```
 string aspNetUserId = "'21F72BCA-A51P-47DF-B57A-C31A191C61D2'";
    DbContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM aspnet_Membership where UserId = " + aspNetUserId);
    DbContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM aspnet_UsersInRoles where UserId = " + aspNetUserId);
    DbContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM aspnet_Users where UserId = " + aspNetUserId);
```

and this works...so now all I need to do is get each individual aspNetUserId from the userName...so i'm trying something like

```
using (DEntities DbContext = DAOHelper.GetObjectContext<DEntities>())
{
var userIdToRemove = DbContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("Select FROM aspnet_Membership where UserName = " + userName);
DbContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM aspnet_Membership where UserId = " + userIdToRemove.UserId);
DbContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM aspnet_UsersInRoles where UserId = " + userIdToRemove.UserId);
DbContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM aspnet_Users where UserId = " + userIdToRemove.UserId);
```

Is something like this possible? setting a var when using EF and if not has anyone else any ideas on how to resolve this...thanks for any replies

Comment: Why are you using SQL statements when you already have a pretty beautiful entity framework library?

Comment: I'm working on existing code created by another user and this is the issue i've met when fixing a bug...dont shoot the editor :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your Select query is wrong:

```
Select FROM aspnet_Membership where UserName = userName
```

Should be

```
Select UserId FROM aspnet_Membership where UserName = userName
```

since you will only need the UserId.

Plus you should use the ExecuteStoreQuery for querying the Database, like this:

```
var userIdToRemove = DbContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>("Select UserId FROM aspnet_Membership where UserName = " + userName);
```

Then of course use userIdToRemove instead of userIdToRemove.UserId